# Calculate the difference between 2 dates and display the value in a field dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a requirement in which I have to calculate the difference between the start date and end date and display the difference between these dates in third field.

I Started writing the component but got struck with calculating difference between dates:

```
<aura:component  >
 <aura:attribute name="StartDate" type="date" />
 <aura:attribute name="EndDate" type="date" />
 <aura:attribute name="TotalDays" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute name="dateValidationError" type="boolean" />


    <div class="slds-box">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap  slds-p-top_small slds-m-around_small">

           <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-m-around_small">
            <lightning:input type="date" aura:id="StartDate" label="Start Date" format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="Select Start Date.."
                                                      value="{!v.StartDate}" required="true" onchange="{!c.dateUpdate}"/>
           <aura:if isTrue="{!v.dateValidationError}">
            <div class="slds-text-color_error slds-p-left_x-small slds-p-top_x-small">
                StartDate cannot be later than end date
            </div>
          </aura:if> 
          </div>

      <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-m-around_small">

            <lightning:input type="date" aura:id="EndDate" label="End Date" format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="Select End Date .."
                                                      value="{!v.EndDate}" required="true" onchange="{!c.dateUpdate}"/>
          </div>

          <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-m-around_small">

               <lightning:input  name="Totaldays" label="Total Days" disabled="true" value="{!v.TotalDays}" />
          </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
    ({


    dateUpdate : function(component, event, helper) {

        var startDateField = component.find("StartDate");
        var startDateFieldValue = startDateField.get("v.value");
        var endDateField = component.find("EndDate");
        var endDateFieldValue = endDateField.get("v.value");
        console.log("EndDateValue", endDateFieldValue);
        var days;

          if(startDateFieldValue && endDateFieldValue )
          {
            if(startDateFieldValue>endDateFieldValue)
            {
              component.set("v.dateValidationError" , true);
             }

        else{



        }


     }
    }


})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting two Date objects gives you a difference in milliseconds; from there, it's just a matter of dividing by 86,400,000 to get the number of days.

```
var startDate = new Date(startDateFieldValue), 
    endDate = new Date(endDateFieldValue),
    days = (endDate-startDate)/8.64e7;
component.set("v.TotalDays", days);
```